# Cordova add plugin cause the reset of files (index.html, css and js files)

Tags: cordova

this is my first time with cordova. But i notice that, when i try to add a new plugin, once the installation finished, all files inside the platform directory are reset to the original state. There's something that i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you update your cordova or add a plugin, the cordova CLI updates your project according to the main www directory.

If you open your project directory you will note that you have the following folders:

```
--hooks
--platforms
--plugins
--www
config.xml
```

So, the above www is the main www for cordova. When you add a plugin, the CLI will update all your www directories inside different platforms to the exact state of the main www located at the same level of the platforms folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i know. I've setting phing on my project and now works good!